# add random walls with an array in 3D xna 4

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0, model-loader

I'm trying to add walls to my 3D game. I created a wall entity and added model array

```
public Walls()
{
  modelArray = new Model[10];
}

public void Initialize(ContentManager contentManager)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < modelArray.Length; i++)
  {
    rnd = new Random();
    sidesWall = rnd.Next(-4, 4);
    forwardWall = rnd.Next(-8, 0);
    modelArray[i] = contentManager.Load<Model>("wall");
  }
}
```

Draw method:

```
public void Draw(Camera camera)
{
  foreach (Model m in modelArray)
  {
    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in m.Meshes)
    {
      foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
      {
        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
        effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
        effect.World = GetWorldMatrix();
        effect.View = camera.ViewMatrix;
        effect.Projection = camera.ProjectionMatrix;
      }

      mesh.Draw();
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and it shows only one wall.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Your draw method shows no translation or rotation of each wall, they will end up on the same spot.
Your world matrix should(could) be

```
World = Matrix.CreateScale(wallscale) * Matrix.CreateRotation(wallRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(wallPosition);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there are many of them but they disappear. But only one appears each time.

 Matrix GetWorldMatrix()
        {
            rnd = new Random();
            sidesWall = rnd.Next(-4, 4);
            forwardWall = rnd.Next(-8, 0);
          
            Matrix translationMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(
                sidesWall, forwardWall, heightOffGround);
          
            Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle);

           
            Matrix combined = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix;

            return combined;
        }

Comment: Are you running GetWorldMatrix each frame? If so, the walls will change location every frame. You should set up this in your Initilize function instead.